# CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString returns no locality...?

Tags: swift, geocoding, cllocationmanager, clgeocoder

Pretty simple code that works to fetch locality info, nearly all city names even if typed text is incomplete/incorrect. Geocoder will return the best matched location which is often correct what you wanted, But, it doesn't work for Tokyo, Tokyo, JP, Tokyo, Japan, Hong Kong... and may be some others?

Anyone knows the reason why?

Placemark -> name: Optional("Tokyo") **locality: nil** country: Optional("Japan") sublocality: nil administrativeArea: Optional("Tokyo") subAdm: nil

```
geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(searchText) { (placemarks, error) in

    if let placemarks = placemarks, placemarks.count > 0, let placemark = placemarks.first {

    completion(placemark)
    }

}
```